# Virtual microphone, networks and vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, virtual, microphone

I would like to add a virtual microphone (similar to how you can have a virual CD drive and then mount ISO files on it.) so that it can be selectable in programs like MSN and skype. But have the source of the audio be streamed from over a network(I know how to stream the audio over the network in VB.net) but how do I get that audio which has been streamed as the input to the virtual microphone?

Jonathan

Comment: Virtual Microphone - that's a new one....what are you using exactly to do this?

Comment: I have not got one yet, I'd like to know how to use/create one.

Comment: Virtual microphones are used all over the shop, epecially in VOIP apps. Simply put they record a waveform, into a file, which can be streamed using a streaming server like media server, or across a messaging protocol like Skype, and heard at the other end. Just need to find a suitable API.

Comment: Does it need to be an API. Can it be an app, which you can wire up, behind the scences...

Comment: All i want to do is recieve a stream over a network (from the vb.net app) and then play that through a virtual mic into apps like skype.

Comment: Hello, Jonathan. Have you succeeded in your development? Have you tried working with AVStream WDK sample? I'm trying to do the same as you want. But I cannot register AVStream as a "native" audio capture device :( Please, help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: No I have no succeeded but I will take another look

Comment: Btw, today I've looked through AVSHwS from AVStream example - it's pin-centric, while avssamp is filter-centric. I'm not too familiar with theory for now, but AVSHwS successfully registeres as Video Capture Device! I'm going to study its *.inf to see how can I use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the [AVStream Filter-Centric Simulated Capture Driver WDK Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163433.aspx) from MSDN, dropping video support (`image.cpp`, `video.cpp` etc.) and altering the audio capture pin implementation to provide audio from the network instead of the sample wave file.

Alternatively, you can take a look at the [Microsoft Virtual Audio Device (MSVAD) Sample Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419691.aspx) from MSDN, implemented as a port-class driver (as opposed to the AVStream driver above.)

It is also possible to write a DirectShow source filter and register it as if it corresponded to an audio capture device.

Comment: vladr, thx a lot for your answer! I'm also developing an virtual audio mic and your clue about AVStream helped me a lot. But now I got stuck on how to register it not only as WDM Streaming Capture Device (by default) but as a "real" audio capture device. There's too few information on this topic in web so I ask your help! If you have a working *.inf file or you can give me some clues - I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is this [app](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html), which may answer your question. Its fits most of not all of the requirtements you have, and the best bit is that its around $35 to buy.

Comment: +1 for VAC.  I have used it to record from skype, play sound effects over skype.

Answer (score -1):

If you need a once-off solution for yourself, this might work. But if you're looking to code this specifically, I apologize for a non-programming answer.

In recording device options, setting your Stereo Mixer as the default device will record whatever gets played on your system.

Note that on Vista+ they hid the stereo mixer (it's disabled by default). The trick is to 'show disabled devices', enable it, and setting it as your default.

[recording device options http://i.imagehost.org/0388/mixer.png](http://i.imagehost.org/0388/mixer.png)